# Windows 8 freezes on shutdown/reboot

Tags: windows-8, freeze, shutdown

I have upgraded my Windows 7 machine to Windows 8.

But whenever I shut down/reboot my PC, the display turns off immediately but the status indicators (HDD, power etc.) are still on. It won't turn off even after an hour. I use the power off button to switch off the machine completely.

Don't know what's wrong.

Any suggestion to resolve this?

Hardware details:

- Asus P53E
- Intel Core i5 2nd gen

Additional info:

- Dual boot with Linux Mint, Windows installed on primary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Disable the fast startup](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/6320-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-8-a.html) and check again.

- Go to Control Panel
- Click on the Power Options
- Click on "Choose what the power buttons do
- Next click on "Change settings that are currently unavailable"
- Now uncheck the box "Turn on fast startup (recommended)".

Reboot and test if you still have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is almost certain to be a driver issue. To find out what may be causing the problem, look at the event logs.

Press Windows key + w, which launches the Search box, type: "ev" and you should see 'View event logs'. This may give you a clue about what device/driver is not playing nice.

Answer (score -1):

There's some indication that the problem might be linked to Norton Internet Security 2013; other responders have found that removing version 2013 and installing 2012 solves the problem. On a lark, I removed NIS totally and installed McAfee Security Center.... so far, no hangs on Restart.... might give it a try; trial copies are available...